# can options be added to npm package.json dependencies?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, npm

I have a dependency with the sqlite3 package.

By default, upon install, the sqlite3 package downloads and uses a pre-packaged version of the sqlite3 engine. This can sometimes be a problem when using sqlite3 extensions so there is an option to install it with :

```
npm install --build-from-source --sqlite=/path/to/sqlite sqlite3
```

both "--build-from-source" and "--sqlite" are options that are handled by the sqlite3 package.

Now how can I tell package.json to install my dependency with those options ?

with

```
"dependencies": {
    "sqlite3": "*"
 }
```

obviously i get the equivalent to

```
npm install sqlite3
```

but I cannot find a way to force the --build-from-source and --sqlite options for the sqlite3 package

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative is to use the [scripts](https://npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html) member and setup the install script under the preinstall or postinstall hook:

```
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npm install --build-from-source --sqlite=/path/to/sqlite sqlite3"
},
```

Comment: not ideal because now "npm shrinkwrap" crashes because sqlite3 is not considered a dependency anymore by npm; but accepted because it does the job while developing.

Comment: note: "npm shrinkwrap" can be tricked by adding the dependency into dependencies. The module beeing pre-installed, dependencies: does not re-install

Answer (score 0):

You can set below two environment variables which will work as passing options with `npm install`:

```
export npm_config_build-from-source=true
export npm_config_sqlite=/path/to/sqlite

"dependencies": {
    "sqlite3": "*"
 }
```

Above combination will install `sqlite3` as `npm install --build-from-source --sqlite=/path/to/sqlite sqlite3`. Thanks.