# Including module installation arguments in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, serial-port

I am using the node [serialport](https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport) library, which needs to be installed using the `--unsafe-perm` and `--build-from-source` arguments. I only wants those arguments to be used when installing `serialport`. If I run the following on the command line it works fine:

```
sudo npm install serialport@5.0.0 --unsafe-perm --build-from-source
```

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20006270/can-options-be-added-to-npm-package-json-dependencies), my understanding is that you accomplish that by using the `preinstall` script, like so:

```
"preinstall": "sudo npm install serialport@5.0.0 --unsafe-perm --build-from-source"
```

However, I'm getting the following error when I run that:

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/test/node_modules/.staging'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/test/node_modules/.staging'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/test/node_modules/.staging' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

So it's not running as root event though I have `sudo` specified in the command?

How do I get `serialport` installed through `package.json` with those flags?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this took a while to figure out, but I think I get it now.

It turns out that when you have a `package.json` file that contains a `preinstall` or `postinstall` script that you are executing as root, `npm` will run this with reduced permissions. You have to include the [`--unsafe-perms`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#unsafe-perm) flag to let it execute the script as root. So the long and short is that you need to run

```
sudo npm i --unsafe-perm
```

or you can create a `.npmrc` file with this entry:

```
unsafe-perm = true
```

If you go the `.npmrc` route you don't have to specify `--unsafe-perm` on the command line.

Of course, all of this is only necessary when you are running `npm i` as root, which isn't really safe. So if you create a regular user and give them full access to the directly in which you are installing your packages, you don't have to worry about `--unsafe-perm`.

As for `--build-from-source`, you don't have to worry about that either because when `electron-rebuild` realizes that it can't download the appropriate package for your environment, it will build it for you.